# Method to receive all bytes from a message-framed stream freezes

Tags: c#, tcp

Recently, I studied Message Framing in my own time and decided that I should use the common solution of prepending the message with the length of the actual message. I use the Tcp wrappers for sockets (TcpListener, TcpClient).

**Context:**
Both server and client communicate with base64 encoded serialized objects. On networks with low traffic, the complete data seems to reach its destination in one piece, and can be decoded and then deserialized. However, on networks with high traffic, or low resource availability, I always get a FormatException that the data is not in a proper Base64 format (or similar errors). Here is the method for sending a message:

```
    public void Send(Packet packData)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(clientObject.GetStream());
            string s = SerializeData(packData);
            w.WriteLine(s.Length.ToString() + s);
            w.Flush();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException) { }
        catch (IOException) { CloseObject(); }
    }
```

Now, here is the method I devised for reading the stream on the receiving end. It appears to freeze at the while loop:

```
    private string ReceiveAllDataFromStream(StreamReader r)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        string str = null;
        try
        {
            str = r.ReadLine();
            // find out how many chars are integers, then get the value in int. (this is the length of the message)
            foreach (char f in str) { if (int.TryParse(f.ToString(), out a)) { b++; } else { break; } }
            // reuse "a", it doesn't actually contain the result of the TryParse method called above
            a = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, b));
            // remove these chars (the ints) from the message
            str = str.Remove(0, b);
            // calculate how many chars need to be received to complete this message
            int msgRemaining = a - str.Length;
            int msgAcquired = str.Length;
            if (msgAcquired != a)
            {
                // where i believe the freeze is caused
                while (msgAcquired != a)
                {
                    // make a call to supposedly retreieve these last few chars
                    string s = r.ReadLine();
                    // insert as much of the new string received as "msgRemaining" demands
                    str.Insert(0, s.Substring(0, msgRemaining));
                    // add the total length of the inserted string to the amount already aquired, continue with loop
                    msgAcquired = msgAcquired + s.Substring(0, msgRemaining).Length;
                }
            } return str;
        }
        catch (FormatException) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(b.ToString() + "|" + str.Substring(0, b)); return null; }
    }
```

When I say it freezes, I mean the application goes into an idle state (UI isn't blocked, but I believe that's because this method is running on another thread). What is wrong with my method, and how do I go about fixing it?

Thank you.

Comment: ReadLine will block until a end-of-line is read.  I can see how your while loop will easily block if the end-of-line isn't exactly at the last character you've calculated you're going to read.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thanks for the reply, do you have any idea on how to fix this mess? Should I just switch the communication protocol over to UDP instead?

Comment: I wouldn't use ReadLine unless I'm absolutely sure I know it's going to have an end-of-line character.  I read read `a` characters from the stream then go looking for end-of-lines...

Comment: @PeterRitchie I thought of end-of-line characters as well, but how would I read continually from the stream until such character is found? A while-loop, like I have here, maybe?

Comment: Well, your code only reads `a` characters.  i.e. you haven't provided enough information to know what is *correct* other than what your code shows.  I would simply use `Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)` to read the `a` characters and look for the right newlines, if not found, you've got a runtime error.  Even if you *did* send the right characters, there's no guarantee something else doesn't send you invalid data, crashing your program.  You should be checking for correctness so something else doesn't cause your app to halt.

Comment: @PeterRitchie The main issue I had with using Read is that char[] argument, to convert the char[] to string, must I call ToString() on it? And I will have a go at doing this, but how exactly do I continue reading the stream? A loop, I assume. But what type?

Comment: Your problem now is you're continuatlly reading the stream.  If it doesn't have the data you're looking for (newline) it will read forever until it does.  You could read all available bytes and verify the data before processing.  Or, you could add some checksums to the data to ensure it's correct--but you'll still have the denial of service potential if something sent your app bad data.